# How can I turn a regular string into a keyword?

Tags: python, string

Recently, I have been programming in the language of Python. I've came across the problem of trying to convert a string into a keyword.

Suppose I use a `raw_input()` phrase and turn that string into an object, list, or dictionary.

For example, I can turn the string "Foo" into Foo and assign that name to a python structure.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to do that, so instead of doing it, use a dictionary:

```
answer = raw_input("Enter: ") # Let's assume I enter "Foo"
mydict = {answer: raw_input("Enter a value for {} ".format(answer)} Let's say I enter "5"
print mydict.get('Foo')
# 5
```

Comment: I really like this method. Thank You :)

Comment: Lol, @Haidro, you just milk these questions. Considering you're the accepted answerer on both the dupes mentioned… with the same answer…

Comment: @kojiro Wow, I never even noticed that!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `globals` dictionary if you wish.

```
globals()[raw_input()] = None # whatever "structure" you desire.
print foo
```

The above code would only work if the user actually inputted the string 'foo'. Otherwise it would say `NameError: name 'foo' is not defined`.

But yeah like Haidro said, whatever you're trying to do this for is probably a silly idea.

As @icktoofay noted in the comments, this will only work with the return value of the built-in function `globals()`. Modifying the return value of the built-in function `locals()` will not actually modify the local namespace.

Comment: It should be noted that this *only* works with global variables; modifying the return value of `locals` does not actually change the local variables.

Comment: @icktoofay edited my post to include that bit of info, thank you.